# Using LIKE to compare Capital and small letters in ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to check a field in oracle that has both capital and small letters,
So I have this code

```
Select Column
From TABLE
WHERE Column NOT LIKE '%ABC%' AND Column NOT LIKE '%abc%'
```

Is there a more efficient way that I can use to check for both capital and small letters in one LIKE statement?

Comment: FWIW, Tom Kyte has a nice post on this topic as it pertains to a case insensitive like (or not like) here, https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1560806455855

Comment: Depending on your actual requirement, it may not be just a matter of efficiency, but also of correctness. If the input is `'Abc'` then it will pass your conditions, because it is neither like ABC nor like abc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about uppercasing it:

```
where  upper(column) not like '%ABC%'
```

Comment: or lower(column) not like '%abc%'  :D

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
WITH test
  AS (SELECT 'aaa' TEXT FROM DUAL
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 'AaA' FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'aAA' FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'AAA' FROM DUAL)
SELECT * 
  FROM test
 WHERE text != DECODE(SUBSTR(LOWER(text),1,1),SUBSTR(text,1,1), LOWER(text), UPPER(text));
```